# How to refresh UITableView after app comes becomes active again?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, multitasking

I would like my UITableView to `reloadData` once my app is active again, after a user exits the application. I know I need to implement (in my app delegate):

`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`

but im not sure how to reference the current UITableView?

UPDATE:
My UITableView is a separate controller. It is actually presented as follows

```
AppDelegate > Root View Controller > Pushes UITabBarController modally which has a UITableViewController
```

Comment: Just call `[self.tableView reloadData]` . Does it work for you? What do you mean by reference the current UITableView?

Comment: i think more information about how the tableView is created, is it in the rootdelegate or a seperate controller?

this would be helpful in providing an answer

Comment: Updated my post, my UITableView is managed by a seperate controller

Answer (score 30, accepted):

following up on Ole's answer above

add this when initializing the viewcontroller

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(becomeActive:)
    name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
    object:nil];
```

add the actual method in the controller

```
- (void)becomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"becoming active");
}
```

be sure to clean up the notification

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: what happens when this is run on anything but an iPhone 4?

Comment: You may need to do some macro if else for different iphone version

Comment: How can I determine what phone version the user is running?

Comment: this really is a new question....

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/model

Comment: There's no need to clean up the notification if I have ARC on, right?

Answer (score 3):

If you can't access your view controller from the app delegate, you could also have your controller listen to the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how I can use UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification in my view controller?

Answer (score 0):

you can create your class called `TableViewManager`. in there register list of `UITableView` so that you can refresh any table you want.
it's like this, in your`TableViewManager` class, you have a method called

```
- (void)RefreshTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
if(tableView != nil)
    [tableView reloadData]; }
```